# Get Difference of 2 Paths

Tags: c#, winforms

Say I have

```
string path1 = "C:\\apples";
string path2 = "C:\apples\blah\meh.jpg";
```

How could I get:

```
string diff = "\blah\meh.jpg";
```

Thanks

Comment: Ofcourse I can think of many ways to roll this out myself, but I want to know the way to make effective use of .NET.

Comment: Few seconds in google - [`Path.GetFullPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) + http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Find_common_directory_path#C.23

Comment: @Milo: so get it working and head over to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. If you have a problem, ask here. If you have it solved but want it reviewed: go to CR. If you haven't made an attempt: do that.

Comment: For what it's worth, I think people are quick to jump the gun on these questions. Granted @Milo could have put more effort into this question but I think the problem is not as trivial as others make it seem. The key to the question is to transform both paths into the canonical form (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773569(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: When I started using SO 5 years ago, it was a lot clearer what types of questions can be asked on SO, but now there are so many StackExchange sites for code that I'm all confused.

Comment: What more could I have added to the question?

Comment: Like I said, I can roll out a hacky solutions involving regex, replace string etc, but why bother when .NET far probably can do it more effectively?

Comment: Okay, I'll keep that in mind, I did not know that was a requirement of SO questions. I thought I should state the simplest test case.

Comment: @Milo, there is no magic function that will accomplish exactly what you're looking for but after getting the canonical form for both paths you can easily check if one of the paths is a prefix of the other (.StartsWith) and then if it does, use .SubString to get the remainder of the second. That will be your delta.

Comment: You need to be more specific about (and/or give more examples for) the `\\\` issue. Also, is it just about the tail?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If Path actually contains double slashes (which usually doesn't happen):

1. Replace `\\` with `\` in `path1`
2. Replace `path1` with `Empty String` in `path2`

   ```
   string diff = path2.Replace(path1.Replace(@"\\", @"\"), "");
   ```

Otherwise:

```
string diff = path2.Replace(path1, "");
```

Comment: How do you deal with two "\\" in a row, did you notice my first is "C:\\apple"

Comment: your solution will fail in certain cases..

Comment: @Milo in `path2` also you should use "\\". Otherwise it will give error: unrecognized space sequence.

Comment: @AmitSharma `@` can be used to avoid that error

Comment: @Shaharyar Yes. I know it. But in that case you have to declare it as:  `string path2=@"C:\apples\blah\meh.jpg"`

Comment: there is no \\ in path1, it's one slash. and second path will not compile unless you escape the slashes

Comment: If there'll be. It'll replace

Comment: actually error will be thrown at `\m` in `string path2=@"C:\apples\blah\meh.jpg"`. All other space  sequence has specific meaning like `\a` and `\b` in `path2`

Comment: `@` does not consider any escape sequence and takes the string as it is written. Even `\n` will be written `\n` if there is `@` at the start of the string.